# Stop long running (never-ending) search (in Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes, after I search something (or accidentally click "search for definition), mostly in PHP files, the VS starts never-ending (running blue line) search (and I hear CPU loading during that time). However, I can't cancel that, with neither <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > `Stop`.  What I should do? 
**I even hear how my CPU is loaded during that period and doesn't stop...**

[image]

Comment: This is quite annoying, and of course, it happens 50/50 when I Ctrl+Click on something

Answer (score 3):

Well, I haven't found other workaround till date, than :

- Right Click on any `$variable` name and select `Peek to definition` and VS stops loading.